# Substring in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables in Postgres that I am trying to compare and a having trouble accessing a substring from one and comparing it to another one. I'm very new to Postgres (specifically SQL through PGadmin), so all suggestions are helpful.

I am trying to count the number of ID numbers that are similar between the two tables, but one set of numbers is longer than the other due to a concatenated FIPS code. I don't want to trim the data if I don't have to, so right now I have:

```
select count(ID_A) from server.table1
 where(ID_A is not null
 and ID_A in (select (substring(ID_B from 3 for 8) from server.table 2)))
```

Comment: What are the data types for Id_a and id_B? integer or char / varchar ?

Comment: And what is the issue with your query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer because I get a little catch on your query. If it is a typo I will delete it after you update your original question.

```
select count(ID_A) 
  from server.table1
 where (     ID_A is not null
         and ID_A in (select (substring(ID_B from 3 for 8) 
                        from server.table2)
                     )                    ^
       )                                  |_ This parenthesis is in wrong place
```

Note that it is either a missing parenthesis or a excessive one.

The right query would be:

```
select count(ID_A) 
  from server.table1
 where ID_A is not null
   and ID_A in (select substring(ID_B from 3 for 8) 
                  from server.table2)
```

As @ZiggyCrueltyfreeZeitgeister pointed out, you actually don't need `ID_A is not null` But only if you don't have null values on it.

Comment: If `ID_A` can't be null, then `select count(*) from server.table1 where ID_A in (select substring(ID_B from 3 for 8) from server.table2 where ID_B is not null)` is equivalent, more readable and more efficient.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I decide to left it as the Original question, but I agree that I should have pointed it out.

Comment: @ZiggyCrueltyfreeZeitgeister and Jorge Campos, you both have been very helpful. I Implemented Ziggy's code because it is more readable but your input was really helpful. Thanks for helping out a novice!